# Erro ao usar FuelPhp na versao 7

Tags: php, php-7

Gostaria de saber se alguem ja encontrou um erro semelhante ao usar o framework FuelPHP, na versao 1.7 com o PHP 7.

Esta estourando a seguinte mensagem, antes de entrar na aplicação:

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Error::error_handler() in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivo\fuel\core\bootstrap.php:100 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivo\fuel\core\bootstrap.php(43): {closure}(8, 'Undefined varia...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 43, Array) #1 [internal function]: {closure}() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivo\fuel\core\bootstrap.php on line 100
```

---

Apos logar na aplicação:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Error::exception_handler() in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivo\fuel\core\bootstrap.php:84 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Fuel\Core\Database_Exception)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivo\fuel\core\bootstrap.php on line 84

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Error::error_handler() in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivo\fuel\core\bootstrap.php:100 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivo\fuel\core\bootstrap.php(43): {closure}(8, 'Undefined varia...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 43, Array) #1 [internal function]: {closure}() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\arquivo\fuel\core\bootstrap.php on line 100
```

---

Stacktrace do bootstrap.php

```
set_exception_handler(function (\Exception $e)
{
    // reset the autoloader
    \Autoloader::_reset();

    // deal with PHP bugs #42098/#54054
    if ( ! class_exists('Error'))
    {
        include COREPATH.'classes/error.php';
        class_alias('\Fuel\Core\Error', 'Error');
        class_alias('\Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException', 'PhpErrorException');
    }

    return \Error::exception_handler($e);
});

set_error_handler(function ($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
{
    // reset the autoloader
    \Autoloader::_reset();

    // deal with PHP bugs #42098/#54054
    if ( ! class_exists('Error'))
    {
        include COREPATH.'classes/error.php';
        class_alias('\Fuel\Core\Error', 'Error');
        class_alias('\Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException', 'PhpErrorException');
    }

    return \Error::error_handler($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
});
```

Cheguei a ver este link, mas nao me ajudou muito =/

https://github.com/fuel/core/issues/1942.

---

A principio a aplicação foi montada em cima do php 5.6.*.

Banco de dados esta rodando tudo certinho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando uma versão do FuelPHP que [não tem suporte para o PHP 7.](https://github.com/fuel/core/issues/2003)

Atualize para a versão 1.8, renomeando a classe `\Fuel\Error` para `\Fuel\Errorhandler`. Mais detalhes você pode encontrar [no *changelog* do FuelPHP](https://github.com/fuel/core/wiki/Changelog-v1.8).

Comment: Obrigado pelas informacoes :D.
Me ajudou bastante.

Pelo que estava vendo havera muitas mudanças de uma versao para a outra. Preciso fazer poucas mudanças. Vou utilizar versão antigas por enquanto.

Comment: @JulioCesarSouza é bom manter atualizado. Ele tem features novas mas nada que vai quebrar o que já existe, pois é um minor version.